# MYSQL GROUP BY doesn't return the first row in a ordered select

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having a problem with returning some rows in an ordered / grouped query.

I'm trying to get the latest row of type 2 on a table, so I used a ORDER first GROUP later approach.

Example table:

```
id    type   field1     date (dd/mm/yyyy)
1     1      texta      01/01/2019
2     1      textb      02/01/2019
3     2      textc      01/01/2019
4     2      textd      02/01/2019
5     2      texte      03/01/2019
```

If I do

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type = 2 ORDER BY date DESC
```

it returns:

```
id    type    field1     date
5     2       texte      03/01/2019
4     2       textd      02/01/2019
3     2       textc      01/01/2019
```

Then if I do

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type = 2 ORDER BY date DESC ) a 
GROUP BY a.type
```

I gets:

```
id    type    field1     date
3     2       textc      01/01/2019
```

Does GROUP BY don't get the first row of the group? How can I get the latest row like:

```
id    type    field1     date
5     2       texte      03/01/2019
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: This is most likely the MySQL bug present in MySQL before 5.7.5, where MySQL did not enforce columns should be either present in the `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregated.

Comment: MySQL is notorious for allowing `GROUP BY` without aggregates etc in the result columns if it's not in strict mode. It will return whatever row in the group it wants to. Don't use such queries.

Comment: Thank you! So, which is the right way to get the latest row of each type in a table?

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, to the best of my knowledge, your query should work ok. Maybe it's a matter of MySQL versions as suggested in the comments

As pwe your question, the solution should be to arrive to the solution not using `GROUP BY`. how about `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT`
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type = 2 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

In this case, the order by brings the needed row first, the limit makes only one row to be returned

Another approach, less efficient, is by `LEFT JOIN` + `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
LEFT JOIN cars2 ON cars.type = cars2.type AND cars2.date > cars.date
WHERE type = 2
AND cars2.id IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

In that approach, the inequality enforces tye latest row not to be joined to the other table
filtering by that criteria will extract the last row

Answer (score 0):

> to get the latest row of each type

you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.* 
from cars c 
where not exists (
  select 1 from cars
  where type = c.type and date > c.date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of the rows in group by for non-aggregated columns, so the query you wrote will not work consistently and will produce non-deterministic values.

To get the data that you wanted, you can perform the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars
WHERE date = (SELECT date FROM cars WHERE type = 2 ORDER BY date DESC limit 1)
```

In your query you are grouping by type but trying to get all other columns which are not part of the aggregation, so it will not work correctly, and in case `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled, the query will be considered invalid.

- Related information for group by can be found in [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: This solution helped me a lot, I made some changes in the SELECT beacuse my real table is more complex. Thank you.